# Morphlines: How to remove everything from _attachment_body

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

As in the title does anyone know how to delete everything within _attachment_body?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setValues command -

```
{
   setValues {
      _attachement_body : []
   }
}
```

[Morphline Reference Guide](http://cloudera.github.io/cdk/docs/current/cdk-morphlines/morphlinesReferenceGuide.html#/setValues)